# Iterate through an array with vba to update MS access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hello I am trying to find out how to iterate through a list to update an access table.

products table has a column for barcode as well as status. The status options are instock, backordered, discontinued.

I have a list of barcodes that can are stored in excel or I can run query but I need to iterate through a list of barcodes to mark each item as discontinued. Haven't done this before any help would be great thanks.

Comment: give me some information so I can make a more complete answer. Are these bar codes in column A starting at row 1?

Comment: barcode Status
3485 Discontinued
1835 Discontinued
2233 Discontinued
1616 Discontinued
1733 Discontinued
3491 Discontinued
2158 Discontinued
2235 Discontinued
2385 Discontinued
2499 Discontinued
7898 Discontinued
1890 Discontinued
2065 Discontinued
2255 Discontinued
2505 Discontinued
7903 Discontinued
7899 Discontinued

Comment: column a = barcode, column b = status which is discontinued

Answer (score 1):

The methods below assume that you have either imported the data from the Excel file or linked to it from within Access.

**Query Method:**
If you have the discontinued barcodes in a table or query, you can use this update query (recommended way for simple cases like yours):

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRODUCTS.STATUS = "DISCONTINUED"
WHERE PRODUCTS.BARCODE IN (SELECT BARCODE FROM OLD_BARCODES);
```

**VBA Method:** If you insist on using VBA, you can use this function to loop through both lists of barcodes and update your active list:

```
Function UpdateBarcodeStatus()
    Dim rsDC, rsCur As Recordset

    ' open rs for current barcodes
    Set rsCur = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT BARCODE, STATUS FROM BARCODES")
    ' open rs for discontinued barcodes
    Set rsDC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT BARCODE FROM OLD_BARCODES")

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    rsCur.MoveFirst

    ' loop through all current barcodes
    While Not rsCur.EOF
        rsDC.MoveFirst
        ' loop through discontinued barcodes for each current barcode
        While Not rsDC.EOF
            If rsDC!BARCODE = rsCur!BARCODE Then
                ' edit current barcode status
                rsCur.Edit
                rsCur!Status = "DISCONTINUED"
                rsCur.Update
            End If

            rsDC.MoveNext
        Wend

        rsCur.MoveNext
    Wend

HandleClose:
    ' close recordsets
    rsDC.Close
    rsCur.Close

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    GoTo HandleClose
End Function
```